# Spark : Update HashMap in Spark Application

Tags: apache-spark, hashmap, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am processing logs in a spark application . I create a Hashmap out of logs and then process it. As part of processing , i have to update value of one the key . But instead of update it is adding a new key-value in the HashMap. and i am getting error `Reference 'column1' is ambiguous, could be: column1#31, column1#56`

My code looks as follows

```
logs.foreachRDD(rdd => {  
 val newRDD = rdd.map(p => createMap(p))
      .map(p => updateColumns(p))

      val sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(rdd.sparkContext)
      import sqlContext.implicits._
      val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(newRDD, reqschema)

      df.registerTempTable("myTable")

      val df1 = sqlContext.sql("Select column1, column2 from myTable")
}

def createMap(log: String): java.util.HashMap[String, String]={
 ...
}
def updateColumns(map : java.util.HashMap[String, String])={
   map.put("column1", "random") // this statements create a new key column1 instead of updating value exiting key "column1" 

}
```

Anyone knows how can we update HashMap in this case ?

Thanks

Comment: You may not be able to do it, because RDD's are immutable. You may have to `collect()` the data and then perform modification but the only caveat will be that `collect()` works at Driver.

Comment: What are your columns? Do you have multiple "column1"? I only ask because this looks like a SQL error when trying to reference a column that is returned from two tables?

Comment: When i created Map , column1 was added . In 2nd step , i tried to update value for column1 . but apparently instead of updating column1 , it added another column1

Comment: Something is not very clear about your code. Can you add explanation about what do you think each block does ?